# ListFragment onListItemClick don't work anymore with Android 4.1 Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-fragmentactivity

I am testing my app in the new **Android system 4.1 Jelly Bean**, and my `ListFragment` is not working properly anymore.

When I click on a list's row, the function `onListItemClick` is not call anymore. It use to work juste fine on Android 3.0 and Android 2.x

Does anything change into Android 4.x concerning the `ListFragment` or the `onListItemClick` ?

One precision, I am using 'ListFragment' **from the android-support-v4.jar**

```
 android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
```

Here is my `ListFrangment` code :

```
public class MessagesListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pull_to_refresh, null);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         /* some initialization, working fine */
         /* Settings of the list Adapter*/

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         int messagePosition = 0;
         if(position>0){
              messagePosition = position - 1;
          } else {
              Log.e("MessageListView", "[onListItemClick] position is inferior to zero,"
                + " message position is set to 0");
          }
          String expediteur = DomboxHome.messagesService.messagesArrayList.get(messagePosition).getExpediteur();
          String contenu = DomboxHome.messagesService.messagesArrayList.get(messagePosition).getContenu();
          Log.d("MessageListView","[onListItemClick] click on message position : "+messagePosition);

          ((MessagesActivity)getActivity()).onChooseMessageDetails(expediteur, contenu);

     }
```

Comment: If you are using the compatibility package, I am almost certain that some stuff will not work right off the bat. There was this video I watched that said anything thats the latest and greatest will probably not be supported by the newest OS for a bit. So my best guess is that you either find a work around, or wait unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution,

The blame was not on *android-support-v4.jar* but on *android-pulltorefresh* with is a library to implement pull-to-refresh-list.

[Android pull to refresh list](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh)

The library was not fully compatible with Jelly Bean, but it is already fixed by the team (by the way, thank you to the team ! )

[Bug fixed](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/pull/53)

Comment: patch seems to work for me. At least I can scroll and click again.

Answer (score 1):

I found this error in my apps that has the PullToRefresh Library that dont suppport the new Android 4.1

To fix the problem i use a fork of the library

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

This library is awesome. Has new PullToRefreshWebView and PullToRefreshGridView and other features like pulltorefresh from bottom (to pull on the bottom of the list) and other thinks like new animations.